# Connecting to WPA2/PEAP/MSCHAPv2 enterprise wifi networks

Tags: wifi, networkmanager

I am using an Arch Linux setup and am having trouble connecting to my school's wifi using networkmanager. I'm using the nmcli connection editor to set up my system connection.

This is what my network file looks like:

```
[connection]
id=MYID
uuid=MY_UUID
type=wifi
interface-name=wlp3s0

[wifi]
mode=infrastructure
ssid=MY_SSID

[wifi-security]
key-mgmt=wpa-eap

[802-1x]
ca-cert=/etc/ca-certificates/trust-source/anchors/ca.crt
eap=peap;
identity=USERNAME
password=PASSWORD
phase2-auth=mschapv2

[ipv4]
dns-search
method=auto

[ipv6]
addr-gen-mode=stable-privacy
dns-seach=
method=auto
```

When I try to activate the connection, it is stuck on

```
Passwords or encryption keys are required to access the wireless network 'SSID'.
connecting (need authentication)
```

before returning: 'Error: Connection activation failed.'

Here is the output from journalctl -ex (often times it says failed to provide secrets that were required).

```
Mar 17 11:45:50 Amadeus NetworkManager[476]: <info>  [1552837550.4471] device (wlp3s0): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Mar 17 11:45:50 Amadeus NetworkManager[476]: <warn>  [1552837550.4512] device (wlp3s0): Activation: (wifi) asking for new secrets
Mar 17 11:45:50 Amadeus wpa_supplicant[561]: wlp3s0: Failed to initiate sched scan
Mar 17 11:45:50 Amadeus NetworkManager[476]: <info>  [1552837550.9868] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> inactive
Mar 17 11:47:50 Amadeus NetworkManager[476]: <warn>  [1552837670.4562] device (wlp3s0): No agents were available for this request.
Mar 17 11:47:50 Amadeus NetworkManager[476]: <info>  [1552837670.4563] device (wlp3s0): state change: need-auth -> failed (reason 'no-secrets', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Mar 17 11:47:50 Amadeus NetworkManager[476]: <info>  [1552837670.4589] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
Mar 17 11:47:50 Amadeus NetworkManager[476]: <warn>  [1552837670.4610] device (wlp3s0): Activation: failed for connection 'WIFI_NAME'
Mar 17 11:47:50 Amadeus NetworkManager[476]: <info>  [1552837670.4613] device (wlp3s0): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Mar 17 11:47:50 Amadeus NetworkManager[476]: <info>  [1552837670.4643] device (wlp3s0): set-hw-addr: set MAC address to D2:CC:73:CD:EF:AD (scanning)
Mar 17 11:47:50 Amadeus NetworkManager[476]: <info>  [1552837670.5044] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: inactive -> disconnected
Mar 17 11:47:50 Amadeus NetworkManager[476]: <info>  [1552837670.5048] device (wlp3s0): sup,
```